# Is it possible to assign the return of a lambda method to a variable in java?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a function that builds a SQL query with a dynamic amount of `where` clauses.

The SQL query exeuction is stored into a ResultSet, I would like to declare this result set in the `try with resource`. However, this requires the declared elements to implements `AutoCloseable`, and the type `String` does not.

My idea was to use a lambda method, pass it as a parameter of executeQuery in order to use its return as the String parameter, like so:

```
try (Statement s = getStatement(); 
        String test = "test";
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(() -> {
            String query = "build y query here";

            return query;
        });

        )
```

But this gives the following error on `executeQuery`:

> The method executeQuery(String) in the type Statement is not
>   applicable for the arguments (() -> {})

AS well as this on `() ->`:

> he target type of this expression must be a functional interface

Is there a way to do what I want to achieve ?

Comment: Since a `String` is not equivalent to a `FunctionaInterface`, it wouldn't compile. Just call the method that constructs the `query` for you.

Comment: @Naman That is a solution. But what actually prevents me to do it in a lambda ?

Comment: The type-inference and further mismatch prevent you from doing it. for e.g. you cannot even call `s.executeQuery(10)` using the same signature. Since `String` is not an `Integer` and neither is it a `FunctionalInterface`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`executeQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery-java.lang.String-) takes a string. It does not take a `Supplier<String>` or anything similar. It requires the query to be supplied eagerly. The closest thing to what you're suggesting would be:

```
Supplier<String> supplier = () -> {
    String query = "build y query here";

    return query;
};
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(supplier.get());
```

Seeing as the supplier cannot be evaluated lazily, constrained by the signatures that `Statement` provides, there is absolutely no value in doing this. You may as well just extract that to a method.

```
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(buildQuery());

// ...

String buildQuery() {
    String query = "build y query here";

    return query;
}
```

Theoretically, they could add a `Supplier<String>` signature which would allow the `Statement` to defer construction of the query up until the last possible moment. This would likely be in the order of milliseconds later than if it has been constructed eagerly.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use try-with-resources for result set itself:

```
try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    setupParams(ps, params);
    try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
              // process the row                    
        }
    } 
}
```

In general instead of working with fairly low-level (and hence painful ;) ) JDBC you could use libraries like JDBC Template of spring or JDBI

If you totally need to run the queries with plain JDBC, consider reading [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/adding-java-8-lambda-goodness)

It goes a couple of steps further in this direction and comes up with pretty interesting solution